# Python 2 to 3 error

Tags: python

I am trying to convert Python 2 to Python 3 and get the following error:

File "xenia-build", line 48, in main
    vs_version = import_vs_environment()
  File "xenia-build", line 106, in import_vs_environment
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

```
 # Grab Visual Studio version and execute shell to set up environment.
if sys.platform == 'win32':
vs_version = import_vs_environment()
if vs_version == None:
  print('ERROR: Visual Studio not found!')
  print('Please refer to the building guide:')
  print('  https://github.com/benvanik/xenia/blob/master/docs/building.md')
  sys.exit(1)
  return

def import_vs_environment():
"""Finds the installed Visual Studio version and imports
interesting environment variables into os.environ.

Returns:
A version such as 2015 or None if no VS is found.
"""
version = 0

 candidate_path = subprocess.check_output('third_party/vswhere/vswhere.exe -version "[15,)" -latest -format value -property installationPath', shell=False)
 candidate_path = candidate_path.strip()
 tools_path = ''
if candidate_path:
tools_path = os.path.join  (candidate_path, 'vc\\auxiliary\\build\\vcvarsall.bat')
if os.path.isfile(tools_path) and os.access(tools_path, os.X_OK):
  version = 2017
if version == 0 and 'VS140COMNTOOLS' in os.environ:
version = 2015
tools_path = os.environ['VS140COMNTOOLS']
tools_path = os.path.join(tools_path, '..\\..\\vc\\vcvarsall.bat')
if version == 0:
return None
```

Comment: hello Thomas, import_vs_environment() is function?

Comment: if it is import_vs_environment() function so what tyes return value.

Comment: This code is not complete; the question is lacking the definition of `import_vs_environment`. Please refer to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to post a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I think `import_os_environment` is returning a byte instead of string. In Python3, `subprocess.Popen` anything would return a byte.

Try using `vs_version = import_os_environment().decode('utf-8')`

One suggestion, `if not vs_version:` is more pythonic than checking `if vs_version == None`.

Comment: I tried using import_os_environment().decode('utf-8") A no go. I updated the code to include import_os_environment function